# Iterate Over Yaml List with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a variable defined in a vars.yml file that looks like this:

```
trust_table: ['first_hostname', 'second_hostname', ...]
```

I'd like to write an ansible step that will iterate over this list and write each hostname to a new line in a file. Basically the result would look like this:

```
$ cat host_file
first_hostname
second_hostname
...
```

So far I've looked at a few different types of ansible loops, but there doesn't appear to be much regarding looping over lists. I'm open to alternatives, like using some kind of template and then copying the template, but I wanted to check to see if anyone else has done something similar first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a "lineinfile" module that checks if a line exists within a file and if not, it writes the line to that file. You can use a loop to iterate over the list with this module to accomplish this task:

```
- name: Edit File
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/stuff/host_file line="{{item}}" state=present
  with_items:
    - "{{ trust_table }}"
```

This will check each item in the trust_table list against the file, and if it doesn't exist already, the item will be added to the list.